# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TableManager.UpdateSystemFields'

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico

I got the following error while upgrading Kentico into 9.0.

Error1:

> For UpdateSystemFields there is **An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TableManager.UpdateSystemFields'**

Error2:

> As in kentico API reference for 9.0 'UpdateTableByDefinition' funtion is showing removed.

```
bool old = TableManager.UpdateSystemFields;// Getting error1
TableManager.UpdateSystemFields = true;// Getting error1
string schema = FormInfo.GetXmlDefinition();
TableManager tm = new TableManager(null);
tm.UpdateTableByDefinition(dci.ClassTableName, schema);// Getting error2
TableManager.UpdateSystemFields = old;// Getting error1
```

Answer (score 1):

[UpdateSystemFields](https://devnet.kentico.com/docs/8_2/api/html/P_CMS_DataEngine_TableManager_UpdateSystemFields.htm) is not a static member, so you can't access it through the type directly.

This is not valid:

```
TableManager.UpdateSystemFields
```

This is valid:

```
TableManager tm = new TableManager("connectionString");
bool old = tm.UpdateSystemFields;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your "error2". Sounds like this method is depricated and there should be some replacement for that.

The reason for your error 1 is that `UpdateSystemFields` is a *non-static instance member* of `TableManager`, so instead of

```
bool old = TableManager.UpdateSystemFields;
// ...
TableManager.UpdateSystemFields = old;
```

you need to use the instance `tm` you created:

```
TableManager tm = new TableManager(null);
bool old = tm.UpdateSystemFields;
// ...
tm.UpdateSystemFields = old;
```